# Background Image on a navigation menu for current page

Tags: css, background

I've been working on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9aUaK/) as an example of what I want. Basically the "li.current_page_item" has a background image on it. Which I'd like to surround the text when clicked.

**The image size is 146 (W) x 44 (H)**

I am having a little difficulty with it though and looking for some help. I've made the graphic one size, as it seemed the easier way.

Wondering if anyone can help me with it. To make sure the background switches to each active item and obviously prevent the list items from jumping too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having a bit of trouble picturing this despite your example. Could you knock up an image I could look at?

Comment: Sure, Here it is : http://s14.postimage.org/6rnammggx/menu_example.png basically that bg image only applies to the current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two reasons the background image is not fully showing.

The first is because you are setting a `height` and `width` on the `li` tag which is an inline element (so cannot have a set `height` or `width`). So you will need to set this as a `block` or `inline-block` element.

The second is that you are setting the background image on the anchor tag nested within `li.current_page_item` - which does not have the `height` or `width` set. To resolve this, I would just move the background image onto the `li.current_page_item` CSS.

So the following CSS would work:

```
.menu li.current_page_item {
    background: url(http://i42.tinypic.com/2mnhvh0.png) no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
}

.menu li {
    ....
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;     /* for IE7*/
    *zoom:1;              /* for IE7*/
    line-height: 44px;    /* center text vertically */
    text-align: center;   /* center text horizontally */
    ....
}
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/9aUaK/2/**

Comment: Thats excellent. Thanks for that. Managed to get it working correctly. Thanks very much